# Что будет если поставить & перед вводом строчки в scanf

Tags: c

Интересует такой вопрос: что произойдет если поставить & перед вводом строчки в scanf, как здесь:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%s", &str);
```

На моем компиляторе вроде работает верно. Вопрос мне задал мой препод в вузе. Он говорит, что отработает не всегда верно. Всегда ли верно отработает? В чем будет отличие от обычного ввода без знака '&' ?

Comment: Сравните char *str и char str[10] зависит от того как объявлена структура

Answer (score 1):

Адрес массива в стеке совпадает с адресом первого элемента, поэтому работает.

Отличие будет если адрес взять не у массива, а у указателя (причём не обязательно на динамическую память).

https://ideone.com/C094Oa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s1[128];
  int _1[128];
  char *s2 = malloc(128);
  int _2[128];

  printf("s1: %p %p\ns2: %p %p\n", s1, &s1, s2, &s2);

  scanf("%s %s", &s1, &s2);

  printf("s1: %p %p\ns2: %p %p\n", s1, &s1, s2, &s2);

  printf("&s1: <<<%s>>>\n", &s1),   fflush(stdout);
  printf("s1:  <<<%s>>>\n", s1),    fflush(stdout);

  printf("&s2: <<<%s>>>\n", &s2),   fflush(stdout);
  printf("s2:  <<<%s>>>\n", s2),    fflush(stdout);

  return 0;
}
```

```
s1: 0x7ffe2084acc0 0x7ffe2084acc0
s2: 0x55e2357a2260 0x7ffe2084acb8
s1: 0x7ffe2084acc0 0x7ffe2084acc0
s2: 0x55e200666564 0x7ffe2084acb8
&s1: <<<abc>>>
s1:  <<<abc>>>
&s2: <<<def>>>
```

> Ошибка выполнения #stdin #stdout 0s 4216KB